# Is it possible to impose the length for a list attribute of the request body with fastapi?

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

Is it possible to specify the length of a list in the schema of the request body (or response)? There is support for validating the length of a string passed in the url with the *Query* function but I see nothing for lists..
Possible use case would be sending list of floats of fixed size to feed to a ML model.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can either [use the `Field` function](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#field-customisation) with `min_items` and `max_items`:

```
from pydantic import Field

class Foo(BaseModel):
    fixed_size_list_parameter: float = Field(..., min_items=4, max_items=4)
```

.. or you can [use the `conlist` (constrained list) type](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#constrained-types) from pydantic:

```
from pydantic import conlist

class Foo(BaseModel):
    # these were named min_items and max_items in Pydantic v1
    fixed_size_list_parameter: conlist(float, min_length=4, max_length=4)
```

This limits the list to exactly four entries of the `float` type.

Comment: Just an addition, if you are using `Path` parameters along with list as json payload then use `Body(...)` for payload else it will throw `Not a valid list error`. E.g. `def add_item(self, request: Request, list_id: int, payload: conlist(ListItem, min_items=1, max_items=10) = Body(...)):` this is kind of required in version 0.108.0, works fine without `Body(...)` in 0.89.0, not sure if it's a bug.

Answer (score 1):

As of Python 3.9 and Pydantic v2, the recommended way is to use `Annotated` types:

```py
# tested with Python 3.9 & Pydantic 2.6

from typing import Annotated
from annotated_types import Len
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Foo(BaseModel):
  my_list: Annotated[list[str], Len(min_length=1, max_length=1)]


ok = Foo(my_list=["bar"])

# these will throw ValidationError exceptions
too_few = Foo(my_list=[])
too_many = Foo(my_list=["bar", "bar"])
```

References:

- [Pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.6/concepts/types/#composing-types-via-annotated)
- [annotated_types: MinLen, MaxLen, Len](https://github.com/annotated-types/annotated-types?tab=readme-ov-file#minlen-maxlen-len)